# SQL Server - Instead Of Trigger To Validate Multiple Values

Tags: sql-server, validation

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and want to achieve some basic data validation, though I'm not sure of the best way to do it. My current plan is as follows:

1. Have a table ('ValidValues') with fields (TableName, FieldName, Value) to relate valid options to other table/field combinations.
2. Populate 'ValidValues' with all the valid options for any given Table/Field combination.
3. Use an INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE trigger to validate entries against ValidValues using a subquery or join.

An example would be my Address table where I would like to validate the fields 'StreetType' and 'StreetSuffix'.

The table structures can be seen here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gy7k1fgdciftdiz/2014-04-30%2017-50-07.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhiptjpzyx6p6ye/2014-04-30%2017-51-34.png

If I added these records to ValidValues:

```
TableName = 'Address', FieldName = 'StreetType', Value = 'Road'
TableName = 'Address', FieldName = 'StreetType', Value = 'Lane'
TableName = 'Address', FieldName = 'StreetSuffix', Value = 'East'
TableName = 'Address', FieldName = 'StreetSuffix', Value = 'West'
```

How should I code the insert/update trigger to only allow the records that match these fields to be added to the Address table?
I was thinking something like the code below (but with extra for each field to be validated, such as StreetType etc).

Would I be better off using a subquery with EXISTS IN though?
Or is there a smarter way to do this when a trying to validate multiple fields to the same table at once?

```
INSERT INTO Address
    (   
    SELECT *
    FROM Inserted
        JOIN ValidValues
        ON ValidValues.Value= Inserted.StreetSuffix
    WHERE
        ValidValues.FieldName = 'StreetSuffix'
        AND
        ValidValues.TableName= 'Address'
    )
```

EDIT: Actually the above won't work because even if I added a second batch of code for StreetType, it will insert the record as long as it passes the StreetSuffix checks and won't ever get around to checking StreetType.
On that basis, should be I using a bunch of EXISTS IN subqueries with an AND condition, before doing the insert? (it's the only way I can think of at the moment).

Comment: Use the separate lookup table for each type, this will only complicate things in a long run.

Comment: Okay, so a straight forward single column table called VV_Address_StreetSuffix for one, then VV_Address_StreetType for the other etc?